# как запретить браузеру кэшировать данные только одного файла или же как удалить из кэша файл?

Tags: php, google-chrome, кэширование, браузер

Удаляю файл (изображение), который создал в отдельном php и вывел в модальное окно в браузере при помощи ajax запроса (в этом модальном окне и есть кнопка закрытия модалки и удаления изображения -  с помощью функции `unlink()`).

Проблема в том, что после удаления файла из директории - он остаётся в кэше браузера, и если вызвать ещё раз создание изображения после закрытия модалки и *без обновления страницы*, то изображение будет создано и сохранено с новыми данными (создаю различный текст на изображении - не суть вопроса), **но в браузере в новой модалке выведет старый файл (взятый из кэша)**.

Знаю, что надо рыться в **cache-control** или около него, но никак не могу понять **как запретить кэшировать данные только одного файла или же как удалить из кэша данные о нём?**

Вот как выглядит страница, для ясности:

[image: Страница]

Модальное окно:

[image: Модальное окно]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно случайный параметр добавлять к url картинки и каждый раз его менять.
/img.jpg?p=1234